# How can I analyze my projects pub dependencies

Tags: dart, dart-pub

When `pub get` or `pub upgrade` doesn't get the package versions I expect or when there are problems with dependency resolution, how can I find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pub deps
```

To show the constraints on each dependency, use

```
pub deps -s list
```